# How do I remove certain characters using grep

Tags: grep

Using grep, how do I remove the first two characters before a number. For example:
I run something and it prints "V=12345" exactly like that. Using grep how do I get it to just print the numbers themselves (i.e. just "12345")

I've got it down to `grep -Ei 'V'` to just print the "V=12345"

Comment: Why `grep` in particular?

Comment: @melpomene just what was asked we use

Comment: `exactly like that` is that with our without quotes?

Comment: You don't even need to execute `grep` as `bash` can do it itself. `str="V=12345"` then take character 2 onwards `n=${str:2}` and check `echo $n`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk`

```
some commands | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

example:

```
echo "V=12345" | awk -F= '{print $2}'
12345
```

And if its double quoted.

```
echo '"V=12345"' | awk -F'["=]' '{print $3}'
12345
```

Other example:

```
echo "X=34 V=12345 W=6435" | awk -F'V=' '{split($2,a," ");print a[1]}'
12345
```